# Encoding a Dataframe differently than One-Hot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix, one-hot-encoding

Suppose i have a df similar that registers the playable-character picks by each of the 6 players (3v3) in a computer game.

```
data = {'Pick_1_team1': ['A','A','A','B','C'],
        'Pick_2_team1': ['D','D','E','F','F'],
        'Pick_3_team1': ['G','G','A','M','O'],
        'Pick_1_team2': ['Q','Q','S','S','A'],
        'Pick_2_team2': ['V','W','X','A','B'],
        'Pick_3_team2': ['R','X','W','W','R']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_enc = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

When i use panda's get_dummies i will get a sparse df with the following structure (example, not the actual encoding from the example df)

Every Pick-slot has every possible pick (A-Z), for both teams.

```
| P1_T1_A | P1_T1_B | P1_T1_C | ... | P2_T1_A | ... | P3_T1_Z | ... | P1_T2_A | P1_T2_B | ... | P3_T2_Z |
|---------|---------|---------|-----|---------|-----|---------|-----|---------|---------|-----|---------|
| 0       | 0       | 1       | ... | 0       | ... | 0       | ... | 1       | 0       | ... | 1       |
| 1       | 0       | 0       | ... | 0       | ... | 0       | ... | 0       | 1       | ... | 1       |
| 1       | 0       | 0       | ... | 0       | ... | 0       | ... | 0       | 0       | ... | 0       |
```

Which is OK but if you consider a larger input space (with 150+ possible picks) the table grows very large. To make it more manageable i was thinking of somehow encoding it into the following format:

One column per category (character) x 2 for each team, 1 if that character was picked, 0 if not.

```
| T1_A | T1_B | T1_C | ... | T1_Z | ... | T2_A | T2_B | ... | T2_Z |
|------|------|------|-----|------|-----|------|------|-----|------|
| 0    | 0    | 1    | ... | 0    | ... | 1    | 1    | ... | 1    |
| 1    | 1    | 1    | ... | 0    | ... | 0    | 0    | ... | 1    |
| 1    | 0    | 0    | ... | 0    | ... | 0    | 0    | ... | 0    |
```

This would limit the feature numbers to number of picks x number of teams (26 letters * 2 teams) instead of possible picks x number of picks x number of teams (26 letters * 3 picks * 2 teams)
Can panda do this via any built_in function? If not what would be the simplest way to go about this?

Any help appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where are the teams in the original data? There are just picks and letters.

Comment: Thanks, tried to. Basically the way one.hot works is that every colum is split into column+possible_categories. What i would like is to rearrange it to one column (x 2 teams) per possible category, filled with 1 if that character was picked.

Comment: @jezrael nothing wrong! i would have accepted both solutions, except it wont let me. And i was able to generalize Ben.T solution to a different df. Probably because i'm not used to pandas.

Comment: @jcf - Ok, I was surprise, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by first selecting one team with `filter`, `stack` the data and use `str.get_dummies`, then `groupby` level=0 (the rows in original df) and `sum`. `add_prefix` to the columns before `concat` for both teams like:

```
df_ = pd.concat([
            (df.filter(like=f'Pick_{i}').stack()
               .str.get_dummies()
               .groupby(level=0).sum()
               .add_prefix(f'T{i}_')
            ) for i in [1,2] ], 
            axis=1)
print (df_)
   T1_A  T1_B  T1_C  T1_D  T1_E  T1_F  T1_G  T1_M  T1_O  T2_A  T2_B  T2_Q  \
0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1   
1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1   
2     2     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
3     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0   
4     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0   

   T2_R  T2_S  T2_V  T2_W  T2_X  
0     1     0     1     0     0  
1     0     0     0     1     1  
2     0     1     0     1     1  
3     0     1     0     1     0  
4     1     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_dummies` with aggregate `max` if need only `1,0` values or `sum` if need count values:

```
df_enc = (pd.get_dummies(df.rename(columns=lambda x:x.split('_', 2)[-1].replace('team','T')))
            .max(axis=1, level=0)
            .sort_index(axis=1, level=0))
print (df_enc)
   T1_A  T1_B  T1_C  T1_D  T1_E  T1_F  T1_G  T1_M  T1_O  T2_A  T2_B  T2_Q  \
0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1   
1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1   
2     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
3     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0   
4     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0   

   T2_R  T2_S  T2_V  T2_W  T2_X  
0     1     0     1     0     0  
1     0     0     0     1     1  
2     0     1     0     1     1  
3     0     1     0     1     0  
4     1     0     0     0     0
```